# animate background gradient with dynamic color and percent

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-animate, linear-gradients

I have a top color, and current color object. top and current objects contain the color val and percentage.

On click, I wanted to use the two val's color and percentage to dynamically animate the gradient of the background.

I'm cose! I have this working with jQuery css --

```
$('.modal').css({
  background : 'linear-gradient(to bottom, ' + $scope.user.color + ' 0%, ' + $scope.top.color + ' ' + $scope.top.percent + '%)'
});
```

Where I get stuck is, it's not animating. It will pop in the new gradient. Anyway to make it ease in the color changes? Thanks!

Comment: You can't animate gradients...they're treated like images. Just search SO for "animate linear gradient"..

Comment: @Paulie_D [this](https://www.gradient-animator.com/) seems to disagree?

Comment: Go ahead...test it. It's not animating the colors...it's animating the position of the gradient image...that's not the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the point in the right direction, looks like @paulie_d is correct. some hacky methods to exist.